# Encontrar un item de una lista en el DOM y luego hacer scroll hasta el elemento

Tags: angular, typescript

Estoy intendando hacer scroll hacia un elemento dentro de una lista en mi html, lo que ocurre es que el código que tengo se ejecuta antes de que cargue la lista por lo cual nunca lo encuentra. Debido a ésto, estoy usando un timeout para esperar un tiempo mientras se carga la lista de items, esto funciona pero quisiera una opción que NO dependiera del timeout, porque estos tiempos pueden variar dependiendo de muchos otros factores. No se si sea posible con algun observer para el dom o algo que me permita ejecturar la tarea hasta cuando la lista de items este cargada. Mi código actual es éste:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var myList = (document.getElementsByClassName('menu-link') as HTMLCollectionOf<HTMLAnchorElement>);
  let myArray = Array.from(myList);
  var myElement = myArray.find(function(ele: HTMLAnchorElement) { return ele.href.endsWith(someValue!) });
  this.scrollTo(myElement!);
}, 1000);
```

alguna sugerencia??

Comment: Usar callback cuando carga la lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

la solución fue mas simple de lo que pensé. Como la lista se cargaba en otro componente, utilicé una variable `Output()` que emite un `true` en el `ngAfterViewInit()` dentro del componente que se encarga de renderizar la lista.

```
  @Output()
  isMenuLoaded: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.isMenuLoaded.emit(true);
  }
```

Dentro del componente padre cree una funcion que está atada a ese evento

```
<app-menu-list (isMenuLoaded)="onMenuLoadComplete($event)">
</app-menu-list>
```

y desde el archivo typescript verifico cuando ese valor sea true, haga lo demas:

```
onMenuLoadComplete(value: boolean) {
    if(value) {
      //TODO
    }
  }
```

Con eso, me aseguro de que el menu está cargado y puedo realizar la busqueda del item dentro del menú sin ningun problema y sin necesidad de usar el `SetTimeOut()`

Answer (score 1):

Haces bien en buscar otra solución, dado que esperar un tiempo puede no funcionar siempre, quizás por alguna razón la lista tarde más en cargar o simplemente cargue muy rápido y estás añadiendo una espera innecesaria. Dependiendo de cómo estés cargando la lista.

1. Caso general, sin Angular: si es simplemente una lista en el DOM, recuerda que el script debe ejecutarse cuando esté todo cargado (evento DOMContentLoaded). Si quieres esperar a que carguen también los estilos e imágenes completamente, algo necesario para poder conocer bien la posición final del elemento, puedes usar window.onload.
2. Con Angular tienes el [ngAfterViewInit()](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit) para ello si no recuerdo mal. Como su nombre indica se ejecuta después de que la vista haya sido cargada, pero esto suponiendo que la lista ya es parte de la propia vista y no se carga a posteriori.
3. Pero **si la lista carga de forma dinámica**, uses lo que uses, en general tendrás que usar callbacks o promesas. Por ejemplo si carga tras un fetch(), hacer el scroll en el then() de la promesa que devuelve. Y en Angular hay muchos más mecanismos para reactividad, pero es necesario entonces que des más detalles.

Danos más detalle del contexto (sobre todo cómo se construye la lista) y podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: bueno, actualmente, la lista se carga desde un subscription en el ngOnInit(), lo que hace basicamente es llamar a un servicio que me trae los items y los almaceno en una variable menuListItems que es la que uso en el html para mostrarlos en otro componente pasandoselos a travez de un Input() dentro de ese otro componenete